# Does leaving the fan on during an RV a/c cycle time save energy?

Tags: road-vehicles, consumer-products, energy-efficiency

When running an RV a/c during the summer, is it more energy-efficient to let the fan run while the compressor is cycling? Does it cause more wear and tear? Does it even matter if you allow the fan to run?

Comment: Example of the claim: http://www.fplblog.com/ask-the-expert/acsetting/

Comment: I assume "motor home" and "home" are close enough to be considered a duplicate.